Cellular structure of $F_4$
Is there the cellular structure of the Exceptional Lie group $F_4$?
Is there a reference to it?
Thanks

Check out page 10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2131

@AndréHenriques I see a chart of the mod 2 and 3 cohomology of $F_4$ in that reference but not the cell structure the poster asks for.

I don't know of a (minimal) cell structure for $F_4$. But the mod $2$ and mod $3$ cohomology produce e a lower bound on the number of cells required. It is possible that once the OP becomes aware of that lower bound, they will decide that they could not really hope to work effectively with any cell structure for $F_4$.
